# Subset dictionary for keys starting with string

Tags: python, dictionary

How to get the mydict subset for keys starting with/containing 'two' string?

`mydict = {'one,a': 1, 'one,b': 2, 'two,a': 3, 'two,b': 3}`

`{'two,a': 3, 'two,b': 3}`

Comment: How do you check if a string contains a substring? How do you iterate over a dictionary to get its keys? Now put those two ideas together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a dictionary comprehension.

```
subdict = {key: value for (key, value) in mydict.items() if 'two' in key}
```